# How to make this piece of code thread safe?

Tags: java, future, executorservice

This code is part of within a method. The code go through two lists using two for loop. I want to see whether there is a possibility of using multi thread to speed up this process for the two loops. My concern is how to make it thread safe.

EDITTED: more complete code

```
static class Similarity {
        double similarity;
        String seedWord;
        String candidateWord;

        public Similarity(double similarity, String seedWord, String candidateWord) {
            this.similarity = similarity;
            this.seedWord = seedWord;
            this.candidateWord = candidateWord;
        }

        public double getSimilarity() {
            return similarity;
        }

        public String getSeedWord() {
            return seedWord;
        }

        public String getCandidateWord() {
            return candidateWord;
        }
    }

    static class SimilarityTask implements Callable<Similarity> {
        Word2Vec vectors;
        String seedWord;
        String candidateWord;
        Collection<String> label1;
        Collection<String> label2;

        public SimilarityTask(Word2Vec vectors, String seedWord, String candidateWord, Collection<String> label1, Collection<String> label2) {
            this.vectors = vectors;
            this.seedWord = seedWord;
            this.candidateWord = candidateWord;
            this.label1 = label1;
            this.label2 = label2;
        }

        @Override
        public Similarity call() {
            double similarity = cosineSimForSentence(vectors, label1, label2);
            return new Similarity(similarity, seedWord, candidateWord);
        }
    }
```

Now, is this 'compute' thread safe? There are 3 variables involved:

```
1) vectors;
  2) toeknizerFactory;
  3) similarities;

public static void compute() throws Exception {

        File modelFile = new File("sim.bin");
        Word2Vec vectors = WordVectorSerializer.readWord2VecModel(modelFile);

        TokenizerFactory tokenizerFactory = new TokenizerFactory()

        List<String> seedList = loadSeeds();
        List<String> candidateList = loadCandidates();

        log.info("Computing similarity: ");

        ExecutorService POOL = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
        List<Future<Similarity>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
        int totalCount=0;
        for (String seed : seedList) {
            Collection<String> label1 = getTokens(seed.trim(), tokenizerFactory);
            if (label1.isEmpty()) {
                continue;
            }
            for (String candidate : candidateList) {
                Collection<String> label2 = getTokens(candidate.trim(), tokenizerFactory);
                if (label2.isEmpty()) {
                    continue;
                }
                Callable<Similarity> callable = new SimilarityTask(vectors, seed, candidate, label1, label2);
                tasks.add(POOL.submit(callable));
                log.info("TotalCount:" + (++totalCount));
            }
        }

        Map<String, Set<String>> similarities = new HashMap<>();
        int validCount = 0;
        for (Future<Similarity> task : tasks) {
            Similarity simi = task.get();
            Double similarity = simi.getSimilarity();
            String seedWord = simi.getSeedWord();
            String candidateWord = simi.getCandidateWord();

            Set<String> similarityWords = similarities.get(seedWord);
            if (similarity >= 0.85) {
                if (similarityWords == null) {
                    similarityWords = new HashSet<>();
                }
                similarityWords.add(candidateWord);
                log.info(seedWord + " " + similarity + " " + candidateWord);
                log.info("ValidCount: "  + (++validCount));
            }

            if (similarityWords != null) {
                similarities.put(seedWord, similarityWords);
            }
        }
}
```

Added one more relevant method, which is used by the call() method:

```
public static double cosineSimForSentence(Word2Vec vectors, Collection<String> label1, Collection<String> label2) {
        try {
            return Transforms.cosineSim(vectors.getWordVectorsMean(label1), vector.getWordVectorsMean(label2));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("OOV: " + label1.toString() + " " + label2.toString());
            //e.getMessage();
            //e.printStackTrace();
            return 0.0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `This code is part of within a method.` means that block is already thread safe.

Comment: @cosmos The question title is a little misleading. The real question is in the text without a question mark as such.

Answer (score 0):

(Answer updated for changed question.)

In general you should profile the code before attempting to optimise it, particularly if it is quite complex.

For threading you need to identify which mutable state is shared between threads. Ideally as much as that as possible before resorting to locks and concurrent data structures. Mutable state that is contained within one thread isn't a problem as such. Immutables are great.

I assume nothing passed to your task gets modified. It's tricky to tell. `final` on fields is a good idea. Collections can be placed in unmodifiable wrappers, though that doesn't stop them being modified via other references and does now show itself in static types.

Assuming you don't break up the inner loop, the only shared mutable state appears to be `similarities` and the values it contains.

You may or may not find you still end up doing too much serially and need to change `similarities` to become concurrent

```
    ConcurrentMap<String, Set<String>> similarities = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

The `get` and `put` of `similarities` will need to be thread-safe. I suggest always creating the `Set`.

```
        Set<String> similarityWords = similarities.getOrDefault(seed, new HashSet<>());
```

or

```
        Set<String> similarityWords = similarities.computeIfAbsent(seed, key -> new HashSet<>());
```

You could use a thread-safe `Set` (for instance with `Collections.synchronizedSet`), but I suggest holding a relevant lock for the entire inner loop.

```
synchronized (similarityWords) {
    ...
}
```

If you wanted to create `similarityWords` lazily then it would be "more fun".

Comment: what about the "tokenizerFactory" variable, which is used in the 'for' loop? Does that need protection? Also, what about the "vectors" variable used in the 'for' loop? Does that need protection as well?

Comment: @Tom Why do you think it is not thread safe in the first place?

Comment: @cosmos It's currently (apparently) single threaded. However if threading is going to be introduced in any useful way there will need to be some communication between the threads and any shared state treated accordingly.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline, I am looking for a way to make the two 'for' loops execution faster and the updated code is such an attempt.

Comment: What about the "tokenizerFactory" and "vectors" variables? They also look like being shared. Aren't they?

Comment: @user697911 Neither look as if they are mutable (or at least being mutated), though appearances are deceptive. `tokenizerFactory` seems to be used by only one thread.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline, right, tokenizerFactory is only used in one thread. Please take a further look at 'vectors', which is used in the method I just added.

Comment: @user697911 But is it mutated. Maybe, but it doesn't look it.